# Scraping webpage with "nonsensical" tags

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am attempting to build a web scraper to aggregate information on state level House and Senate bills. I am using Python and I can pull the HTML from the page, but parsing it is giving me difficulty. For example, the New Hampshire bill page wraps information in tags with "nonsensically" named tags. Here is an example page: http://www.gencourt.state.nh.us/bill_status/billText.aspx?sy=2017&id=14&txtFormat=html. How would I go about pulling, for example, the number of the bill, from the long list of tags?

Comment: What are the nonsensical tags? It looks like everything is in `<p>` and `<span>`, what's nonsensical about that?

Comment: Do you mean the random-looking classes like `cs2E86D3A6`? I guess you should pick an example and find the classes that correspond with the information you want to pull.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to scrape this HTML rather than hitting an API? Lots of government data is accessible like this. Here's such a thing http://docs.openstates.org/en/latest/api/ they even maintain a client for python to help you out it looks like!

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, I'd say that markup was generated by some sort of WYSIWYG editor. (The presence of invalid CSS properties like `tab-stops` suggests that it might be output from a word processor.) If this is the case, the exact usage of classes in the output is unlikely to be consistent between documents.

With this in mind, your best bet will probably be to ignore the markup entirely and parse the text.

Answer (score 0):

Open the page in a browser, right-click on something you want to be able to pull, and use **Inspect**, to see the class name used for that element. For instance, if you inspect the bill number, you'll see that it's

```
<span class="cs4904F745">76</span>
```

So in your web scraping code, search for the class `cs4904F745` to get the bill number. These things may look random, but I've checked a few documents and they're consistent.

You can use the BeautifulSoup library to parse the HTML and search for what you want.